# How to generate z-scores separately for each factor level using a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

I would like to convert `variable` to z-scores. How to do that for each factor `cell` level separately using a loop?

Example DATA:

```
df = data.frame(Cell = c(rep("13a",5),rep("1b",5),rep("5b",5)),
            condition = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"),3),
            variable = c(58,55,36,29,53,57,53,54,52,52,45,49,48,46,45))
```

Is this a good start?... Maybe the loop is not necessary buy I would like to learn how to write loops...

```
# Final data frame containing the results of all loops
df_z = data.frame() 

# Loop through by cell
for (i in 1:unique(df$Cell)) {
df_z$myZ <-  scale(variable)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with a `group_by` operation

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Cell) %>% 
   mutate(myZ = as.numeric(scale(variable)))
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, myZ := as.numeric(scale(variable)), by = Cell][]
```

---

In the case for `for` loop, we can subset the in each of the iteration and assign the `scale`d values to the created 'myZ' variable

```
un1 <- unique(df$Cell)
df$myZ <- NA
for(un in un1) {
     i1 <- df$Cell == un
     df$myZ[i1] <- as.numeric(scale(df$variable[i1]))
  }
```

Or with `split`

```
df$myZ <- unsplit(lapply(split(df$variable, df$Cell), scale), df$Cell)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ave` in base R :

```
df$myZ <- with(df, ave(variable, Cell, FUN = scale))
df
#   Cell condition variable    myZ
#1   13a         a       58  0.917
#2   13a         b       55  0.684
#3   13a         c       36 -0.792
#4   13a         d       29 -1.336
#5   13a         e       53  0.528
#6    1b         a       57  1.640
#7    1b         b       53 -0.289
#8    1b         c       54  0.193
#9    1b         d       52 -0.772
#10   1b         e       52 -0.772
#11   5b         a       45 -0.881
#12   5b         b       49  1.321
#13   5b         c       48  0.771
#14   5b         d       46 -0.330
#15   5b         e       45 -0.881
```